# Convert JSON member string to JSON object

Tags: json, go

I have this struct:

```
type ResponseStatus struct {
    StatusCode int
    Message    string
    Data       string `json:"data"`
}

type Pets struct {
    Id   int    `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Age  int    `json:"age"`
    Type string `json:"type"`
}
```

and this is my json result:

```
{
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "Message": "Hello framework - OK",
    "data": "[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"george\",\"age\":2,\"type\":\"dog\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"walter\",\"age\":1,\"type\":\"rabbit\"},{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"tom\",\"age\":1,\"type\":\"cat\"},{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"doggo\",\"age\":5,\"type\":\"dog\"},{\"id\":5,\"name\":\"torto\",\"age\":3,\"type\":\"turtle\"},{\"id\":6,\"name\":\"jerry\",\"age\":1,\"type\":\"hamster\"},{\"id\":7,\"name\":\"garf\",\"age\":2,\"type\":\"cat\"},{\"id\":8,\"name\":\"milo\",\"age\":4,\"type\":\"dog\"},{\"id\":9,\"name\":\"kimi\",\"age\":2,\"type\":\"cat\"},{\"id\":10,\"name\":\"buck\",\"age\":1,\"type\":\"rabbit\"}]"
}
```

How can I escaped double quotes in my result data as JSON like this:

```
{
  "StatusCode": 200,
  "Message": "Hello framework - OK",
  "data": [
    {"id": 1,"name": "george","age": 2,"type": "dog"},
    {"id": 2,"name": "walter","age": 1,"type": "rabbit"},
    {"id": 3,"name": "tom","age": 1,"type": "cat"},
    {"id": 4,"name": "doggo","age": 5,"type": "dog"},
    {"id": 5,"name": "torto","age": 3,"type": "turtle"},
    {"id": 6,"name": "jerry","age": 1,"type": "hamster"},
    {"id": 7,"name": "garf","age": 2,"type": "cat"},
    {"id": 8,"name": "milo","age": 4,"type": "dog"},
    {"id": 9,"name": "kimi","age": 2,"type": "cat"},
    {"id": 10,"name": "buck","age": 1,"type": "rabbit"}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing fine, just a few remarks: Remove the quote before and after the square brackets, and you should make Data of type []Pets (which struct I would call Pet, because every item contains a single Pet). The square-brackets are part of the JSON construct. And then you don't need to escape the quotes, because they become JSON identifiers.

In your way, it becomes a single long string, which, clearly, is not what you intent to have.

These are the structures that fit on your second JSON

```
type ResponseStatus struct {
   StatusCode int    
   Message    string 
   Data       []Pet  `json:"data"`
}

type Pet struct {
   Id   int    `json:"id"`
   Name string `json:"name"`
   Age  int    `json:"age"`
   Type string `json:"type"`
}
```